# TCPDF to produce same binary output (no realtime dependencies)

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have a server with limited storage. The idea is to store a document as HTML and convert it to PDF only for download purposes, but not store it.

I can create a PDF with TCPDF each time a PDF is needed. The problem arises when this PDF needs also to be digitally signed. For my server, an external web API is used to send a PDF and it returns the signed PDF to my server.

My idea is to have the signed pdf compared with [xdiff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xdiff.php) with the original PDF I created with TCPDF so I can only store the diff in the database, not the entire bulky PDF.

For that to succeed, TCPDF must be able to produce exactly the same output, given similar input. Is there a way to tell TCPDF to not take any real-time dependency (like the current time)?

```
function PDFConvert($author,$title,$htmls,$clsid)
{
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', true,false);

$pdf->setHeaderData('',0,'','',array(0,0,0), array(255,255,255) );  
$pdf->setFooterData('',0,'','',array(0,0,0), array(255,255,255) );  
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->SetCreator($author);
$pdf->SetAuthor($author);
$pdf->SetTitle($title);
$pdf->SetSubject($title);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->SetKeywords($clsid);
$pdf->SetFont("calibri", '', 12);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($htmls, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();

$pdfstr = $pdf->Output('1.pdf', 'S');
return $pdfstr;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I’m not clear, you want to store the diff of two binary files (that happen to be PDFs) in the database? Why can’t you just diff the source HTML to know if a something has changed and a new signature is needed? Or better, why not a “lasted updated” column?

Comment: Because the signature requires manual interaction with the user. Signing cant be repeatrd

Comment: Have you made sure that that *external web API* used for signing always does so in an incremental update? Otherwise the xdiff diff may encompass the whole PDF...

Comment: The document’s time stamps default to now, so you’d want to call `setDocCreationTimestamp` and `setDocModificationTimestamp` with consistent values

Comment: There’s also a random `file_id` that might be a UUID, but I’m not seeing any way to change it, so you might need to use reflection on it.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks, why don't you post an answer.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, I didn’t test these, nor will I have time over the next week or three probably, so I’d be happy to upvote an answer that shows these in action producing two files over time that are binary identical

Comment: @ChrisHaas I tested them and it works when file_id is same. It produces the same PDF.